# Count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, frequency

I have a dataset

```
category
cat a
cat b
cat a
```

I'd like to return something like the following which shows the unique values and their frequencies

```
category   freq 
cat a       2
cat b       1
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`df["category"].value_counts()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207326/pandas-frequency-table-for-a-single-variable)?

Answer (score 675, accepted):

Use [`value_counts()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) as @DSM commented.

```
In [37]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abssbab')})
df['a'].value_counts()

Out[37]:

b    3
a    2
s    2
dtype: int64
```

Also `groupby` and `count`. Many ways to skin a cat here.

```
In [38]:
df.groupby('a').count()

Out[38]:

   a
a   
a  2
b  3
s  2

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

See [the online docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html).

If you wanted to add frequency back to the original dataframe use `transform` to return an aligned index:

```
In [41]:
df['freq'] = df.groupby('a')['a'].transform('count')
df

Out[41]:

   a freq
0  a    2
1  b    3
2  s    2
3  s    2
4  b    3
5  a    2
6  b    3

[7 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: `df.groupby('a').count()` doesn't work if you have multiple columns. It will give you a ncol x nvals dataframe. That's nice when you only have one column, but when you have 10's or 100's of columns, the result is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: That `groupby` solution doesn't work; you just get an empty df out. Seems like it used to work in the past though, so I edited the answer to move it down, but left it in for posterity.

Comment: `df.groupby('a')['a'].count()` does work though, or `df.groupby('a').size()` from [Vidhya's answer](/a/38703649/4518341)

Answer (score 126):

If you want to apply to all columns you can use:

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts)
```

This will apply a column based aggregation function (in this case value_counts) to each of the columns.

Answer (score 108):

```
df.category.value_counts()
```

This short little line of code will give you the output you want.

If your column name has spaces you can use

```
df['category'].value_counts()
```

Comment: Or use **[]** if the column name has space. `df['category 1'].value_counts()`

Answer (score 24):

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)
```

[value_counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) - Returns object containing counts of unique values

[apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) - count frequency in every column. If you set `axis=1`, you get frequency in every row

fillna(0) - make output more fancy. Changed NaN to 0

Answer (score 22):

In 0.18.1 `groupby` together with `count` does not give the frequency of unique values:

```
>>> df
   a
0  a
1  b
2  s
3  s
4  b
5  a
6  b

>>> df.groupby('a').count()
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [a, b, s]
```

However, the unique values and their frequencies are easily determined using `size`:

```
>>> df.groupby('a').size()
a
a    2
b    3
s    2
```

With `df.a.value_counts()` sorted values (in descending order, i.e. largest value first) are returned by default.

Answer (score 8):

As everyone said, the faster solution is to do:

```
df.column_to_analyze.value_counts()
```

But if you want to use the output in your dataframe, with this schema:

```
df input:

category
cat a
cat b
cat a

df output: 

category   counts
cat a        2
cat b        1 
cat a        2
```

you can do this:

```
df['counts'] = df.category.map(df.category.value_counts())
df
```

Answer (score 7):

Using list comprehension and value_counts for multiple columns in a df

```
[my_series[c].value_counts() for c in list(my_series.select_dtypes(include=['O']).columns)]
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28192263/786326

Answer (score 7):

If your DataFrame has values with the same type, you can also set `return_counts=True` in [numpy.unique()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

`index, counts = np.unique(df.values,return_counts=True)`

[np.bincount()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) could be faster if your values are integers.

Answer (score 5):

Without any libraries, you could do this instead:

```
def to_frequency_table(data):
    frequencytable = {}
    for key in data:
        if key in frequencytable:
            frequencytable[key] += 1
        else:
            frequencytable[key] = 1
    return frequencytable
```

Example:

```
to_frequency_table([1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4])
>>> {1: 4, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this with pandas by broadcasting your columns as categories first, e.g. `dtype="category"` e.g.

```
cats = ['client', 'hotel', 'currency', 'ota', 'user_country']

df[cats] = df[cats].astype('category')
```

and then calling `describe`:

```
df[cats].describe()
```

This will give you a nice table of value counts and a bit more :):

```
    client  hotel   currency    ota user_country
count   852845  852845  852845  852845  852845
unique  2554    17477   132 14  219
top 2198    13202   USD Hades   US
freq    102562  8847    516500  242734  340992
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should work fine for any DataFrame columns list.

```
def column_list(x):
    column_list_df = []
    for col_name in x.columns:
        y = col_name, len(x[col_name].unique())
        column_list_df.append(y)
return pd.DataFrame(column_list_df)

column_list_df.rename(columns={0: "Feature", 1: "Value_count"})
```

The function "column_list" checks the columns names and then checks the uniqueness of each column values.

Comment: You can add a brief explanation of how your code works to improve your answer.

Answer (score 2):

@metatoaster has already pointed this out.
 Go for `Counter`. It's blazing fast.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import timeit
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10000, (100, 2)), columns=["NumA", "NumB"])
```

## Timers

```
%timeit -n 10000 df['NumA'].value_counts()
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 715 µs per loop

%timeit -n 10000 df['NumA'].value_counts().to_dict()
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 796 µs per loop

%timeit -n 10000 Counter(df['NumA'])
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 74 µs per loop

%timeit -n 10000 df.groupby(['NumA']).count()
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop
```

Cheers!

Comment: Well, it depends very much on the size of the dataframe: if you run the benchmark (thanks for sharing!) for `(100000, 2)`, pandas' `value_counts()` becomes the fastest option.

Answer (score 1):

The following code creates frequency table for the various values in a column called "Total_score" in a dataframe called "smaller_dat1", and then returns the number of times the value "300" appears in the column.

```
valuec = smaller_dat1.Total_score.value_counts()
valuec.loc[300]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n_values = data.income.value_counts()
```

**First unique value  count**

```
n_at_most_50k = n_values[0]
```

**Second unique value  count**

```
n_greater_50k = n_values[1]

n_values
```

**Output:**

```
<=50K    34014
>50K     11208

Name: income, dtype: int64
```

**Output:**

```
n_greater_50k,n_at_most_50k:-
(11208, 34014)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your data:

|category|
cat a
cat b
cat a
```

solution:

```
 df['freq'] = df.groupby('category')['category'].transform('count')
 df =  df.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR: `value_counts()` is the way to go. All other methods are inferior

On top of it being idiomatic and easy to call, here are a couple more reasons why it should be used.

##### 1. It is faster than other methods

If you look at the performance plots below, for most of the native pandas dtypes, `value_counts()` is the most efficient (or equivalent to) option.<sup>1</sup> In particular, it's faster than both `groupby.size` and `groupby.count` for all dtypes.

[image: perfplot]

##### 2. It can make bins for histograms

You can not only count the frequency of each value, you can bin them in one go. For other options, you'll have to go through an additional `pd.cut` step to get the same output. For example,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(100)})

bins = [-float('inf'), 33, 66, float('inf')]
df['col'].value_counts(bins=bins, sort=False)


(-inf, 33.0]    34
(33.0, 66.0]    33
(66.0, inf]     33
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

##### 3. More general than `groupby.count` or `groupby.size`

The main difference between `groupby.count` and `groupby.size` is that `count` counts only non-NaN values while `size` returns the length (which includes NaN), if the column has NaN values.

`value_counts()` is equivalent to `groupby.count` by default but can become equivalent to `groupby.size` if `dropna=False`, i.e. `df['col'].value_counts(dropna=False)`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Code used to produce the perfplot:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import perfplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gen = lambda N: pd.DataFrame({'col': np.random.default_rng().integers(N, size=N)})
setup_funcs = [
    ('numeric', lambda N: gen(N)),
    ('nullable integer dtype', lambda N: gen(N).astype('Int64')),
    ('object', lambda N: gen(N).astype(str)),
    ('string (extension dtype)', lambda N: gen(N).astype('string')),
    ('categorical', lambda N: gen(N).astype('category')),
    ('datetime', lambda N: pd.DataFrame({'col': np.resize(pd.date_range('2020', '2024', N//10+1), N)}))
]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(15, 15), facecolor='white', constrained_layout=True)
for i, funcs in enumerate(zip(*[iter(setup_funcs)]*2)):
    for j, (label, func) in enumerate(funcs):
        plt.sca(axs[i, j])
        perfplot.plot(
            setup=func,
            kernels=[
                lambda df: df['col'].value_counts(sort=False),
                lambda df: pd.Series(*reversed(np.unique(df['col'], return_counts=True))),
                lambda df: pd.Series(Counter(df['col'])),
                lambda df: df.groupby('col').size(),
                lambda df: df.groupby('col')['col'].count()
            ],
            labels=['value_counts', 'np.unique', 'Counter', 'groupby.size', 'groupby.count'],
            n_range=[2**k for k in range(21)],
            xlabel='len(df)',
            title=f'Count frequency in {label} column',
            equality_check=lambda x,y: x.eq(y.loc[x.index]).all()
        );
```