# Count frequency of values in pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

I want to count number of times each values is appearing in dataframe.

Here is my dataframe - `df`:

```
    status
1     N
2     N
3     C
4     N
5     S
6     N
7     N
8     S
9     N
10    N
11    N
12    S
13    N
14    C
15    N
16    N
17    N
18    N
19    S
20    N
```

I want to dictionary of counts:

ex. `counts = {N: 14, C:2, S:4}`

I have tried `df['status']['N']` but it gives `keyError` and also `df['status'].value_counts` but no use.

Comment: I wonder why I can't directly use df['status'].value_counts()[my_key] and must use the to_dict() first?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
print df['status'].value_counts()
N    14
S     4
C     2
Name: status, dtype: int64

counts = df['status'].value_counts().to_dict()
print counts
{'S': 4, 'C': 2, 'N': 14}
```

Comment: Nice solution - using only pandas

Comment: Nice solution. I can then treat it as a normal dictionary, and use it this way - counts[my_key].
However I wonder why I can't directly use df['status'].value_counts()[my_key] and must use the to_dict() first?

Answer (score 14):

An alternative one liner using underdog `Counter`:

```
In [3]: from collections import Counter

In [4]: dict(Counter(df.status))
Out[4]: {'C': 2, 'N': 14, 'S': 4}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try this way.

```
df.stack().value_counts().to_dict()
```

Comment: Why do we stack?

Answer (score 2):

Can you convert `df` into a list?

If so:

```
a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
c = dict()
for i in set(a):
    c[i] = a.count(i)
```

Using a dict comprehension:

```
c = {i: a.count(i) for i in set(a)}
```

Answer (score 1):

See my response in this thread for a Pandas DataFrame output,

[count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column/55952449#55952449)

For dictionary output, you can modify as follows:

```
def column_list_dict(x):
    column_list_df = []
    for col_name in x.columns:        
        y = col_name, len(x[col_name].unique())
        column_list_df.append(y)
    return dict(column_list_df)
```