# Count the frequency of characters at a position in a string in a Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question related to the `df['columnA'].value_counts()` method and a previous post here: [Count frequency of values in pandas DataFrame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004976/count-frequency-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe-column)

Take this example DataFrame:

```
fake_data = {'columnA': ['XAVY', 'XAVY', 'XAVY', 'XAVY', 'XAVY', 'AXYV', 'AXYV', 'AXYV', 'AXYV', 'AXYV', 'AXYV']}
df = pd.DataFrame(fake_data, columns = ['columnA'])
df
```

**I am trying to determine the frequency of each letter (X,A,V,Y) at each position in the string in this column.**

In this example, position 0 would be 54% A, 46% X, position 3 would be 46% Y, 54% V...and so on.

Comment: won't position 3 be 50% V and 50%Y. Just wondering if I got you question right

Comment: Yes! Will correct typo.

Comment: Its a suggestion and thus a comment - write a method ```def countFreq(df)```  which will count occurrence of  X in series/column - record. Pass your ```df[columnA]``` as an input parameter to this method. Within the ```countFreq(df)``` create a DICT , with keys like , ```dictFreq['X'] ``` and ```dictFreq['A'] ``` , etc . Append count of letters to these dict keys as values.

Comment: can you post the desired output too, how exactly it should look like?

Comment: Replies below, especially from Akash Kumar, have resolved problem. From his answer, I would add that if you want the frequency at a particularly position: stats.iloc[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
new_data = df.columnA.str.split('',n=4, expand=True).drop(0, axis=1)
stats = new_data.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
stats = stats.apply(lambda x: (x/x.sum())*100).round(2).fillna(0)
print(stats)
```

Output

```
    1      2    3     4
A   54.54 45.45 0     0
V   0     0     45.45 54.54
X   45.45 54.54 0     0
Y   0     0     54.54 45.45
```

Comment: I believe there is a typo in the first line: new_data = df.columnA.str.split('',n=4, expand=True).drop(0, axis=1)

Answer (score 4):

First convert the string to a list and then expand to columns. Then count values and calculate percentage of occurence for each letter.

```
(
    df.columnA.apply(list)
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .apply(pd.value_counts)
    .apply(lambda x: x.div(x.sum()))
    .fillna(0)
)

    0           1           2           3
A   0.545455    0.454545    0.000000    0.000000
V   0.000000    0.000000    0.454545    0.545455
X   0.454545    0.545455    0.000000    0.000000
Y   0.000000    0.000000    0.545455    0.454545
```

Answer (score 2):

This expand the linked post:

```
ddf = df['columnA'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(list(x)))
counts = ddf[c].value_counts() / ddf[c].value_counts().sum() for c in ddf.columns]
```

`counts` is a list with a series produced by `value_counts()` for each column. So to check position 0, you do `counts[0]`. And it will gives:

```
A    0.545455
X    0.454545
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to begin with

```
>>> df.columnA.str.split('', expand=True).apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
      0    1    2    3    4     5
   11.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  11.0
A   NaN  6.0  5.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
V   NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0  6.0   NaN
X   NaN  5.0  6.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
Y   NaN  NaN  NaN  6.0  5.0   NaN
```

This way columns at 0 and 5th positions are empty, and can be ignored.