# Count frequency of number appearance in full pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen several posts giving solutions to counting frequencies of either numbers or categories *by column* in a pandas data frame, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004976/count-frequency-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe-column). If I have a data frame n x m having only numeric, I want to do the same for the entire data frame, how do I do that without first flattening it into one column/vector? Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried `.value_counts()` on the whole dataframe? Like `df.value_counts()`

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Hi, yes, but it counts the occurence of the entire row, not each number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy` for this:

```
values, counts = np.unique(df, return_counts=True)

for v, c in zip(values, counts):
    print(v, c)
```

for dataframe like

```
   a  b
0  1  2
1  1  3
```

it will output

```
1 2
2 1
3 1
```