# Frequency of elements matching results in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Pandas DataFrame and I am trying to create a list `freqs` that contains the frequency of elements of a column (of the DataFrame) matching the last column of the DataFrame.

```py
freqs = []
for i in range(len(df.colums)-1):
    counter = 0
    result = row[-1]
    for row in df.iterrows():
        if row[i] == result:
            counter += 1
    freqs.append(counter / len_df)
print(freqs)
```

This is the code I have written but I find it too slow and less close to the panda way of solving it.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html - try value_counts with normalize=True.

Would that work?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results? I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense to me. You're iterating over columns with `i` and then calling `row[i]` for each row?

Answer (score 0):

The below line should help...

```
df['ColumnName'].value_counts().to_dict()
```

Associated Documentation : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

This might be a duplicate of : [Count frequency of values in pandas DataFrame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004976/count-frequency-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe-column) and so, if the answer helps - kindly close this question.