# Pandas find how many times a column value appears in dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort data by the `Name` column, by popularity.

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
df['Count'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(df[df['Name'] == x['Name']]), axis=1)
df[df['Count'] > 50][['Name', 'Description', 'Count']].drop_duplicates('Name').sort_values('Count', ascending=False).head(100)
```

However this query is very slow, it takes hours to run.

What would be a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please provide example DataFrame!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column

Comment: @Lynob worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I have been looking for is:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby('Name')['Name'].transform('count')
```

Big thanks to @Lynob for providing a link with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]], columns=['a', 'b'])
print(df['b'].value_counts())
```

outputs

```
1    2
0    1
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Right, but I need the other fields from df as well ('Name', 'Description'). `value_counts` omits those.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = ["jim"]*5  + ["jane"]*10 + ["john"]*15 
n = pd.Series(a)

sorted((n.value_counts()[n.value_counts() > 5]).index)

['jane', 'john']
```

Comment: I would still like to know the fields like 'Name', 'Description' from my df. So I guess, what would be a way to apply `value_counts()` to my `df.apply` method to create new column called 'Counts'?

Comment: You need to provide some data or example dataframe.

Comment: I made sample data answer beacuse comments are impossible to work with.