# Sort by Frequency of Values in a Column - Pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe

Fruits
Apple
                                                                Mango
Banana
Apple
                                                                Mango
Banana
Apple
                                                                Mango
Grapes

I want to sort this column by Frequency of the values occurring in it, So the dataframe now should be:

Fruits
Apple
                                                                Apple
Apple
Banana
                                                               Banana
Banana
Mango
                                                                Mango
Grapes

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a freq column and then sort by freq and fruit name.

```
df.assign(freq=df.apply(lambda x: df.Fruits.value_counts()\
  .to_dict()[x.Fruits], axis=1))\
  .sort_values(by=['freq','Fruits'],ascending=[False,True]).loc[:,['Fruits']]
Out[593]: 
   Fruits
0   Apple
3   Apple
6   Apple
1   Mango
4   Mango
7   Mango
2  Banana
5  Banana
8  Grapes
```

A similar approach by using groupby and count:

```
df.assign(freq=df.groupby('Fruits')['Fruits'].transform('count'))\
  .sort_values(by=['freq','Fruits'],ascending=[False,True]).loc[:,['Fruits']]
```

###### To view all columns:

```
df.assign(freq=df.groupby('Fruits')['Fruits'].transform('count'))\
  .sort_values(by=['freq','Fruits'],ascending=[False,True])
```

Comment: This works but I have a multi-column dataframe so how can I display all columns?

Comment: For anyone referencing this post in the future, in response to mLstudent33, to display all columns with the first method (the method for which the answer was accepted), you would just get rid of ".loc[:,['Fruits']]"