# Python 3 pandas : Transform Data Frame to get levels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, frequency

I am using python 3 pandas.

My data frame looks like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['eve', "A", True],['eve', 'C', True], ['nathan', 'B', False],['eve', 'C', True], ['eric', 'C', True],['eric', 'D', True]]),
                   columns=['Name', 'Level', 'Date'])
```

output :

```
    Name    Level   Date
0   eve     A   True
1   eve     C   True
2   nathan  B   False
3   eve     C   True
4   eric    C   True
4   eric    D   True
```

I would like to get :

```
Name    Level    Date

Eve     A        True
        C        True
        C        True

eric    C        True
eric    D        True 
nathan  B        False
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['eve', "A", True],['eve', 'C', True], ['nathan', 'B', False],['eve', 'C', True], ['eric', 'C', True]]),
                   columns=['Name', 'Level', 'Date'])
```

You can do to order rows by the `Name` column:

```
df.sort_values('Name')
```

Which will give you this:

```
    Name    Level   Date
4   eric    C   True
0   eve     A   True
1   eve     C   True
3   eve     C   True
2   nathan  B   False
```

Ie in a notebook:

[image]

If you want to order rows by frequency of its content in the `Name` column, you can do, relying on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44363729/8565438) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18145399/8565438):

```
sorteddf = df.assign(frequency = df.groupby('Name')['Name'].transform('count')).sort_values(by=['frequency'],ascending=False).drop('frequency',1)
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: Is this sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: thanks I would like to sort it by the occurent 'eve' (as eve has 3 rows)  to the least occurent