# How do I create the counts of the column values, grouped by values in the other column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, unique

I have a dataframe df that has values:

```
ID    Status
1       A
2       B
5       A
1       A
3       B
4       B
5       B
```

I need to group column ID by the column Status. The issue is that ID can have duplicates, that can have the same or different codes.

The code I have is:

```
df_new = df.groupby('ID').Status.nunique()
```

However, I am getting IDs grouped, without showing the Status column and their values. What I need to create is a dataset that looks like this:

```
Status  Count
  A      3
  B      4
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `groupby` and `count`:

```
df.groupby('Status')['Status'].count()
```

Output:

```
Status
A    3
B    4
Name: Status, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Why not `df.Status.value_counts()`?

Comment: I thought of that too on my drive home.  I was going to edit this answer.  Thanks, John for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Pandas, but I know SQL, and underlying concept of what you're doing is the same. You need to aggregate your data with a count function, first. Then you can group by that status column.

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html

Also, see this similar SO answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/22391554/5129424

Pasted gist of answer here in case the link goes away:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abssbab')})
df.groupby('a').count()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for `DataFrame`:

```
df = df['Status'].value_counts().rename_axis('Status').reset_index(name='Count')
print (df)
  Status  Count
0      B      4
1      A      3
```

Or aggregate by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df = df.groupby('Status').size().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df)
  Status  Count
0      A      3
1      B      4
```

EDIT:

But if want get size by column `ID`, another column is not necessary:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID')['Status'].size().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df1)
   ID  Count
0   1      2
1   2      1
2   3      1
3   4      1
4   5      2

df2 = df.groupby('ID')['ID'].size().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df2)
   ID  Count
0   1      2
1   2      1
2   3      1
3   4      1
4   5      2

df3 = df.groupby('ID').size().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df3)
   ID  Count
0   1      2
1   2      1
2   3      1
3   4      1
4   5      2
```

But is possible use:

```
df4 = df.groupby('ID')['Status'].value_counts().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df4)
   ID Status  Count
0   1      A      2
1   2      B      1
2   3      B      1
3   4      B      1
4   5      A      1
5   5      B      1
```

What is same as:

```
df4 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Status']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df4)
   ID Status  Count
0   1      A      2
1   2      B      1
2   3      B      1
3   4      B      1
4   5      A      1
5   5      B      1
```

[What is the difference between size and count in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346591/what-is-the-difference-between-size-and-count-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

For the output that you wish to create, a **value_counts** method on the variable **Status** would be sufficient.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','B','A','A','B','B','B'])
df.columns=['Status']
df.Status.value_counts()
```