# Count_values with where condition to count values of one column with respect to other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing some EDA on my data which is pandas data-frame and I am stuck at this point. I don't know how to count values of infants where party== republican or democrat. I want to apply value_counts on all columns where arty== republican or democrat.

```
   party infants water budget physician salvador religious satellite 
republican  n     y      n         y        y         y         n   
republican  n     y      n         y        y         y         n   
democrat    ?     y      y         ?        y         y         n   
democrat    n     y      y         n        ?         y         n   
democrat    y     y      y         n        y         y         n
```

Answer should be like

```
party           infants 
democrat.    y=1, n=1, ?=1
republican   y=0, n=2, ?=0
```

like that for all columns. I have tried something like that.

```
infants_count = data["infants"].value_counts().where(data['party']=="democrat")
infants_count.loc['y']
```

Comment: I have tried this but It doesn't work. I don't know where I am mistaken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column)

Comment: @Bazingaa above mentioned question can be answered with data.infants.value_counts(). But my case is different

Comment: Did you try using `groupby`?

Comment: @Bazingaa I am trying it like that.
 grouped = data.groupby('party')
print (grouped.count())
print (grouped.infants.value_counts()). It seems to work but does't it?

Comment: I wish I could try solving it but currently I will have to write your DataFrame myself in a code form.

Comment: I can't graph it like that.    
     party       infants
    democrat    y          156
                      n          102
                      ?            9
     republican  n          134
                        y           31
                       ?            3<code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df_out = df.groupby('party')['infants'].value_counts().unstack(0).fillna(0)

df_out.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.index +'='+x.astype(int).astype(str)))\
      .rename('infant')\
      .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        party       infant
0    democrat  ?=1,n=1,y=1
1  republican  ?=0,n=2,y=0
```

#### Update to answer comment below:

```
df_out = df.groupby('party')['infants'].value_counts().unstack(-1).fillna(0)

df_out
```

Output:

```
infants       ?    n    y
party                    
democrat    1.0  1.0  1.0
republican  0.0  2.0  0
```

Plotting

```
df_out = df.groupby('party')['infants'].value_counts().unstack(-1).fillna(0)
ax = df_out.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Select a single value:

```
df_out.loc['democrat','y']
```

Output:

```
1.0
```

Comment: Thanks you, It is doing what I want but can i get value of y or n from infant column separately?

Comment: there are 16 columns like infants. how this dataframe will work for graphs?

Comment: can you write a code to show me how i can get y for democrat from infants? please remember there are many columns like infants.