# pandas count number of occurrences of values in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long dataframe with only one column and around 800k rows. my data frame looks like this

```
54
53
53
53
53
...
0
0
0
```

So what I need is to count the number of occurrences of each value and saving this into a dataframe so the result would be something like this

```
54 1
53 1000
52 800
...
0 100000
```

I have tried using `df.groupby(0)` but it only returns an object. How can I get a two-column dataframe (or 1 column and a row-index showing the values)?

Comment: use `df['column_name'].value_counts()` or `df['column_name'].value_counts().to_frame()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `value_counts` and `to_frame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,4,5,5], columns=['values'])
df['values'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'values', 'values':'count'})

 values count
0   5   2
1   4   1
2   2   1
3   1   1
```