# Count frequencies of values in different columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My data has the following shape:

```
id   column1   column2
a    x         1
a    x         3
a    y         3
b    y         1
b    y         2
```

And I want to get to most repeated value for each id as well as its frequency percentage.

```
id   column1  %     column2  %
a    x        66.6  3        66.6
b    y        100.0 N/A      N/A
```

a special case is when there are equal frequencies, I output N/A for both column and percentage.

Right now my solution is purely using python dictionaries and lists. However, I am struggling to approach this from a DataFrame point of view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A (very) similar solution to @Wen, but accounts for the condition where the ratios of a group are the same, and the result should be `NaN`:

```
u = df.groupby('id')
c = ('column1', 'column2')

def helper(group, col):
    return (group[col].value_counts(normalize=True, sort=True)
            .drop_duplicates(keep=False)
            .groupby(level=0).head(1)
            .to_frame(f'{col}_%')
            .reset_index(level=1))

pd.concat([helper(u, col) for col in c], axis=1)
```

```
  column1  column1_%  column2  column2_%
a       x   0.666667      3.0   0.666667
b       y   1.000000      NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would add ``dropna=False`` to value_counts() and voila!

Answer (score 4):

I can only think of for loop then concat

```
g=df.groupby('id')
pd.concat([ g[x].value_counts(normalize=True).groupby(level=0).head(1).to_frame('%').reset_index(level=1) for x in df.columns[1:]],axis=1)
Out[135]: 
   column1         %  column2         %
id                                     
a        x  0.666667        3  0.666667
b        y  1.000000        1  0.500000
```

Comment: Glad to see you around (-:

Comment: @piRSquared yeah , I am back Sir

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth...
This feels more natural to me:

```
s = pd.Series(
    Counter([
        (i, c, v) for (i, c), v in df.set_index('id').stack().items()
    ])
)

d = s.groupby(level=[0, 1]).pipe(lambda g: [*zip(g.idxmax(), g.max() / g.sum())])

a = {}

for ((i, col, var), val) in d:
  a[(i, col, 'var')] = var
  a[(i, col, 'val')] = val

pd.Series(a).unstack([1, 2])

    column1       column2    
        val var       val var
a  0.666667   x  0.666667   3
b         1   y       0.5   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply`

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','a','a','b','b'],'column1':['x','x','y','y','y'],'column2':[1,3,3,1,2]})


def get_max(row):
    tem_dict=Counter(row)
    return(tem_dict.most_common()[0][0], float(tem_dict.most_common()[0][1])/sum(tem_dict.values()))

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('id')['column1'].apply(get_max).tolist(),columns=['Column1','%']),
           pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('id')['column2'].apply(get_max).tolist(),columns=['Column2','%'])],axis=1)
```