# Counting the number of times a value appears in a list

Tags: python, count, int

This is my starting point. I have separated the specific column of my data which I want to count the specific number of times 0 and 1 appear

[image]

```
print(sr.count(0))

AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'levels'
```

I have tried using the above code but it states and as evident the AttributeError shows up.

Comment: Is that a pandas dataframe? (I'm wondering if those would be relevant tags for this Q.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make it a list first:

```
print(sr.tolist().count(0))
```

Then it would be good.

Output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Collections has a Counter class, try:

```
from collections import Counter
cntr = Counter() 
cntr.update(sr.tolist())
```

cntr will now have sr as its keys and the count of them as its values. Hope that helps.