# linear checking for count of repeated data's in series

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to count how many repeated data are there in each column in DataFrame.

This is a python 3.7.

I have tried df_.count(),but it is meant for axis.
I expect the outcome to looks like:

```
    1   2
0   a   b 
1   a   b
2   b   c
3   c   a
4   a   c

column1.count(a)=3 column2.count(a)=1
column1.count(b)=1 column2.count(b)=2
column1.count(c)=1 column2.count(c)=2
```

and the count will be of further use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

```
df.column_name.value_counts()
```