# How to find the number of an element in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have a dataframe A likes below :

```
   a b c
x  0 2 1
y  1 3 2
z  0 2 4
```

I want to get the number of 0 in column 'a' , which should returns 2. ( A[x][a] and A[z][a] )

Is there a simple way or is there a function I can easily do this?

I've Googled for it, but there are only articles like this.

[count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22391433/9543663)

Which makes a new dataframe, and is too complicated to what I only need to do.

Comment: Have you tried: `A.a.eq(0).sum()` ?

Comment: @Jon Clements Is this method only use in series? seems like not for a dataframe.

Comment: You can apply `eq` (or any comparison methods) to DataFrames if you want... I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sum` with boolean mask - `True`s are processes like `1`, so output is count of `0` values:

```
out = A.a.eq(0).sum()
print (out)
2
```

Comment: Is this method suitable for dataframe?

Comment: @黃立銘 you can try it... if you wanted to get a count by column of how many zeros are present in each column, you could do `A[A == 0].sum()` for instance

Comment: I try A.a.eq(0).sum() successfully, while (A['a'] == 0).sum() doesn't work. Still thank you a lot !

Answer (score -1):

Try `value_counts` from pandas ([here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)):

```py
df.a.value_counts()["0"]
```

If the values are changeable, do it with `df[column_name].value_counts()[searched_value]`

Comment: This is definitely more expensive than simply indexing on the values which are `0`

Comment: A little overkill as this'll build a Series of all unique values and their counts only to just take a single value...