# Pandas groupby count is result is ignoring .count()?

Tags: python, pandas

The following code does not give an error, but is ignoring the `.count()` part as per the picture below. It is returning 1 column, when I expected 2? any idea why? thanks.

```
df = df.filter(['StartsWith'])
df = df.groupby(['StartsWith']).count()
df
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you chopped off half of the picture. `GroupBy` sets your column which you want to group by on as index. Use `df.groupby(['StartsWith']).count().reset_index()` to get your `StarstWith` back as column.

Comment: df.groupby(['StartsWith']).size().reset_index()

Comment: See marked duplicate, in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38703649/9209546).

Comment: @Erfan no I didn't chop off anything..that was the exact output. However, your comment about the index was quite helpful. When I changed df.filter(['StartsWith']) with df.filter(['StartsWith','Source']) the output showed the count. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `.count()` by `.size()`.