# Summing up a Pandas dataframe, single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a single column and 1200 rows.
There are a total of 3 possible values in each row - 'No difference', 'Opposite sex' or 'Same sex'. The column header is 'Friends'
I'm trying to sum up the total number of results for each value using

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['Friends']).sum()
```

but I end up with an empty dataframe as the result (df2)

Comment: Welcome so stack overflow! If you have a single column, then you have a series, not a dataframe. Perhaps the `series.value_counts()` method might help here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
df2 = df1['Friends'].value_counts()
```

Comment: I think you have a period at the wrong place

Comment: @NicolasGervais thanks!

Comment: That did it - thank you