# Count values in column. Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

**1.I want to count how many males and females are in my "sex" column in excel.**

I tried `sex_value = df.groupby("sex").size()` but there are space in some of them in. eg. `"F "` and `"F"` (the same is with `"M" "M "`)

If everything were like `"M" or "F"` I would use:

```py
sex_value = df.groupby("sex").size() 

Output:
sex
F           37
F           27
M           40
M           31
dtype: int64
```

In my case it should be something like

```py
sex_value_female = df[(df['sex']=='F') & (df['sex'] == 'F ')].sum()
sex_value_male = df[(df['sex']=='M') & (df['sex'] == 'M ')].sum()
```

but it doesnt work.

**2. The same problem is with mean value.**

```py
#mean value of brainweight and bodyweight for males and females
mean = df.groupby('sex').agg({'bodywt': 'mean', 'brainwt': 'mean'})

Output:
             bodywt     brainwt
sex                            
F         19.696216  410.059459
F         21.262963  440.122222
M         21.669750  410.030000
M         22.870968  433.709677
```

Comment: `df['sex'].value_counts()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column)

Comment: what if you first do : df.sex = df.sex.str.strip() and then df.groupby("sex").size()

Comment: @Ehsan it worked well. Thank you!

Comment: would you mind to accept it as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's do strip to get ride of whitespace

```
df.sex = df.sex.str.strip()
sex_value = df.groupby("sex").size()
```