# pandas find value counts of column

Tags: python, pandas

From a data frame I want to count how many rows have same value for each unique value in a column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,1,2,2,3,3],'l1':['a','a','a','a','b','b'],'l3':['b','a','b','a','a','a'],'l4':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
cols = ['c','l1']
out = (df.set_index(cols).assign(pair=df.groupby(cols)['l3']
         .agg(makePair)).reset_index()
         .reindex(df.columns.union(['pair'],sort=False),axis=1))
    out['l1'].value_counts
```

I got wiered results as

```
<bound method IndexOpsMixin.value_counts of 0    a
1    a
2    a
3    a
4    b
5    b
Name: l1, dtype: object>
```

**I expect**

```
a 3
b 2
```

And actual ask is to do the value count on 'pair' ie `out['pair'].value_counts` where the error was more complicated

[image]

Comment: `pd.Series.value_counts` is a method, which you need to call with `()`, so `out['l1'].value_counts()`

Comment: @ALollz I've edited my answer based on your comment. thanks

Comment: already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use value_counts()

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,1,2,2,3,3],'l1':['a','a','a','a','b','b'],'l3':['b','a','b','a','a','a'],'l4':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
df['l1'].value_counts() # l1 is your column name
```

[image]

But, its already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column). Next time google before asking!

Comment: Do you mean df['l1'].. The user Seems to have tried that option and posted the results.

Comment: @user2458922 mine works, his doesn't work

Comment: I got it.. The Difference was value_counts VS value_counts() . Need to know whats value_counts doing