# How to sum # of rows of a column containing a categorical variable in Python

Tags: python, data-analysis

Let's say my data frame has a column 'genus', and it contains 5 rows each that contain 'seed', 'flame', 'turtle', and 'shellfish'.

How can you get Python to add up each category and print out a total count for each category? I want to be able to apply a function that will automatically do this for each unique category in the column 'genus' without having to go and parse out each unique category.

I would want to see something like:
seed: 5
flame: 5
turtle: 5
Shellfish: 5

(yes, this is a Pokemon dataset )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column)

Comment: There we go. Thanks! I `used:df['genus'].value_counts()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work,

```
df['genus'].value_counts()
```

or

```
df.genus.value_counts()
```