# How to aggregate data in Panda data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using panda data frame to handle data. Now I would need to aggregate data and wondering how.

I have `df`:

```py
      Car  Country
0  Toyota    Japan
1  Nissan    Japan
2     BMW  Germany
3    Ford       US
```

I would like to create `df2` with print:

```py
Japan      2
Germany    1
US         1
```

Comment: you are looking for [value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count the frequency that a value occurs in a dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391433/count-the-frequency-that-a-value-occurs-in-a-dataframe-column)

Comment: please don't call it 'panda'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @luigigi, use pandas method [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Car": ["Toyota", "Nissan", "BMW", "Ford"], "Country": ["Japan", "Japan", "Germany", "US"]})
df["Country"].value_counts()
```