# How to create a column by applying the command `for`?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, group-by

I did the `for` command, to know how many times the ID repeats in the `dateframe`, now I need to create a column indexing the total in the respective ID.

In short, I need a column with the repeat total of `df['ID']`, how to index a total of the groupby command?

```
test = df['ID'].sort_values(ascending=True)

rep = 0
for k in range(0,len(test)-1):
  if(test[k]==test[k+1]):
    rep += 1
    if(k==len(test)-2):
      print(test[k],',', rep+1)
  else:
    print(test[k],',', rep+1)
    rep = 0
```

out:

```
> 7614381 , 1 
> 349444 , 5 
> 4577800 ,7
```

Comment: It's usually wrong to write `for` loops when using pandas or numpy, because they provide built-in methods that automatically process the entire dataframe or array.

Comment: I need a column with the repeat total of df['ID'], how to index a total of the groupby command? For example, a column with the total number of times that given df['ID'] appeared in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

"For example, a column with the total number of times that given df['ID'] appeared in the dataframe"

Is this what you mean?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
     {'id': [7614381, 349444 ,349444, 4577800, 4577800 ,349444, 4577800]}
 )

df["id_count"] = df.groupby('id')['id'].transform('count')

df
```

Output

```
     id       id_count
0  7614381         1
1   349444         3
2   349444         3
3  4577800         2
4   349444         3
5  4577800         2
```

based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22391554/11323137